# Does "seemed" have the same meaning as "as though"

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> A. It seemed as though the war had ended.
>
> B. It seemed the war had ended.

What is the difference between these two sentences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't have the *same* meaning. If it did, then you could use either one. But you can't:

> ✔ It **seemed** the war had ended.
>   ✘ It **as though** the war had ended.

---

The term [*as though*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20though) is defined as a conjunction by Merriam-Webster:

> : as if
>   //  the applause was so great it was *as though* the toddler's dance class had been the Bolshoi Ballet

In the case of the sentence in the question, there are many variations that could also be used:

> It seemed the war had ended.
>
> It seemed **as though** the war had ended.
>   It seemed **as if** the war had ended.
>   It seemed **like** the war had ended.
>   It seemed **that** the war had ended.

---

As indicated by Merriam-Webster, *as though* is synonymous with *as if*. In this case, *as if*, *like*, and *as though* all act in such a way as to turn the sentence into a simile:

> The surface of the water was *like* a mirror, reflecting my face.
>   The surface of the water, *as though* a mirror, reflected my face.
>   The surface of the water, *as if* a mirror, reflected my face.

Neither the version with only *seemed* on its own nor the version with *seemed that* have the same sense of simile.

Therefore, from a semantic perspective:

> ✔ It seemed *as though* the war had ended, ***but it hadn't***.
>   ✔ It seemed *as if* the war had ended, ***but it hadn't***.
>   ✔ It seemed *like* the war had ended, ***but it hadn't***.

But:

> ✘ It seemed the war had ended, ***but it hadn't***.
>   ✘ It seemed that the war had ended, ***but it hadn't***.

The last two don't make sense, because they don't have the same sense of simile that the others do. Hearing them, you'd think the speaker was confused. Was the war over or wasn't it?

---

In short, *seemed* on its own is a simple description of the situation:

> It seemed the war ***had*** actually ended.

Adding *as though* to it, turns the sentence into a simile. With the addition of *as though*, it's no longer talking about the *actual* situation, it's drawing a comparison between it and something else:

> Although it seemed **as though** the war had ended, it actually ***hadn't***.

Answer (score 0):

That is an interesting question. I'm a native UK English speaker and I cannot discern any fundamental difference in meaning in these sentences whether or not "as though" is included.

It does, somehow, seem more appropriate to use "as though" in the first case,

> It seemed as though the war had ended.

does feel better that

> It seemed the war had ended.

but I would be hard pressed to define why.

Comment: Would you feel better if the second sentence had "that" in it: *It seemed that the war had ended*?

Comment: yes, though I still prefer "as though" - I suspect that we're into an issue of style and personal preference rather than one of correctness.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, you are right. I actually can't make up my mind on which of the two I prefer.